# Why is a checkbox posting a value of on

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a a checkbox like so:

```
<label for="TBMasterProduct.BloodTestEnabled">Blood Test Enabled?</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="TBMasterProduct.BloodTestEnabled" id="TBMasterProduct_BloodTestEnabled" class="cb" />
```

When I submit the form its sending the value 'on' against TBMasterProduct.BloodTestEnabled

Why would a checkbox post that value? Surely it should be true/false

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why would a checkbox post that value?

Browsers default to a value of `on` if you don't set one explicitly with a `value` attribute.

At the time this answer was written, this was non-standard error recovery. In HTML 4, [the `value` attribute is **mandatory** for checkboxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-value-INPUT). HTML 5 [makes the attribute optional with a default of `on`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#modedef-input-default-on).

> Surely it should be true/false

No. Either the checkbox is checked (and thus successful) so the value gets submitted, or it isn't and the checkbox doesn't appear in the submitted data at all.

An individual checkbox may have a boolean state, but multiple inputs can share a name to group them. The values then distinguish which items in the list were selected.

Comment: Interresting point about the mandatory attribute. The W3C validator doesn't flag that as an error, however.

Comment: DTDs are not expressive enough to make an attribute mandatory only when another attribute has a certain value. Validation is excellent for the low hanging fruit of QA, but it isn't the whole story.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a 'value' set on your checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

No, it should not be true/false.

The value from the checkbox is only included in the form when it's checked. If it's not checked, there is no value at all sent.

The value that is sent is the one that you specify using the `value` attribute. If you don't specify a value, the default value `"on"` is used.